# Docker and casual work/dev on virtual machine and IDE

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a general question about good practices and lets say way of work between docker and IDE.

Right now i am learning docker and docker compose, and i must admit that i like the idea of containers! Ive deployed my whole spring boot microservices architecture on containers, and everything is working really well!

The thing is, that in every place of properties when i am declaring localhost address, i was forced to change localhost to custom container names, for example localhost:8888 --> naming-server:8888. It is okay for running in containers, but obviously when i am trying to run this on IDE, it will fail. I like working/optimizing/debugging microservices in IDE, but i dont want rebuilding image and returning whole docker-compose every time i made a tiny small change.

What does it look like in real dev?

Regards!

Comment: You can add entries in /etc/hosts file on your host running IDE to point to localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my day job there are at least four environments my code can run in: my desktop development environment, a developer-oriented container environment, and pre-production and production container environments.  All four of these environments can have different values for things like host names.  That means they *must* be configurable in some way.

If you've hard-coded `localhost` as a hostname in your application source code, it will not run in any environment other than your development system, and it needs to be changed to a configuration option.

From a pure-Docker point of view, making these configurable via environment variables is easiest (and Spring can set property values from environment variables).  Spring also has the notion of a *profile*, which in principle matches the concept of having different settings for different environments, but injecting a whole profile configuration can be a little more complex at deployment time.

The other practice I've found helpful is to have the environment variable settings default to reasonable things for developers.  The pre-production and production deployments are all heavily scripted and so there's a reasonably strong guarantee that they will have all of the correct environment variables set.  If `$PGHOST` defaults to `localhost` that's right for a non-Docker developer, and all of the container-based setups can set an appropriate value for their environment at deploy time.

Even though our actual deployment system is based on containers (via Kubernetes) I do my day-to-day development in a mostly non-Docker environment.  I can run an individual microservice by launching it from a shell prompt, possibly with setting some environment variables, and services have unit tests that can run just on the checked-out source tree, without needing any Docker at all.  A second step is to build an image and deploy it into the development environment, and our CI system runs integration tests against the images it builds.